# React Js Stripe setup intent for apple/google pay card

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I want to confirm setup intent for stripe payment request button.

I have tried using confirmSetup provided in `@stripe/react-stripe-js`
ButI'm getting `your card number is incomplete`
Note: I've default card setup in my browser.

here is the code I'm using.
I have two options here

1. User is trying to make a payment
2. Trying to save user card as setup intent

```
    pr.on("paymentmethod", async (event) => {
      // Confirm Payment intent
      let errorResponse;
      if (type !== "plugin") {
        const { error, paymentIntent } = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(
          stripeClientSecret,
          {
            payment_method: event.paymentMethod.id,
          },
          {
            handleActions: false,
          }
        );
        errorResponse = error;
         // site first to authorize the payment
        if (paymentIntent.status === "requires_action") {
          stripe.confirmCardPayment(stripeClientSecret);
        }
      }else{
        const {error, } = await stripe.confirmSetup({elements, confirmParams: {return_url: returnUrl}});
        // const {error} = await stripe.confirmCardSetup(subscription.stripeSetupIntent.client_secret, )
        console.log({error});
        
        errorResponse = error;
      }
      
      // handle error on failure
      if (errorResponse) {
        event.complete("fail");
        return;
      }
      event.complete("success");
     
      // redirect to the `return_url`.
      window.location.href = `${origin}${STRIPE_PAYMENT_CONFIRMED_PATH}?subscription_type=${type}`;
    });
```

Comment: Please share the exact code you're using and exact details of the error(when does it happen, when calling which function, etc).

Comment: Okay I will update the question

Comment: That code you shared looks like it's using the PaymentRequestButton. You can't use confirmSetup with that, you need to use confirmCardSetup, and pass the PaymentMethod ID you got. It would look the same as the code you have for confirmCardPayment earlier.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the comment, i got help from stripe discord channel. it's exactly as you mentioned